# The mysql query can not group by name for some days

Tags: mysql

I had a mysql query, I want to group by name for some days. Now, it just group by name for one day, I don't know where problem is , could you help please.

```sql
SELECT attendance.username,
       attendance.date,
       attendance.time_in,
       attendance.time_out,
       attendance_count.count_time,
       attendance_count.appendix
FROM attendance
LEFT JOIN attendance_count
    ON (attendance.date=attendance_count.date)
        AND (attendance.username = attendance_count.username)
WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(attendance.date, '%m/%d/%Y')
    BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01/21/2013', '%m/%d/%Y')
        AND STR_TO_DATE('02/20/2013', '%m/%d/%Y'))
GROUP BY attendance.username
```

Comment: I'm not reading that. Go find an SQL formatter.

Comment: add  attendance.date to group by

Answer (score 0):

'For some days' is ununderstandable. Please provide more info about it.

```
SELECT attendance.username,
       attendance.date,
       attendance.time_in,
       attendance.time_out,
       attendance_count.count_time,
       attendance_count.appendix
FROM attendance
LEFT JOIN attendance_count
    ON (attendance.date=attendance_count.date)
    AND (attendance.username = attendance_count.username)
WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(attendance.date, '%m/%d/%Y')
    BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01/21/2013', '%m/%d/%Y')
    AND STR_TO_DATE('02/20/2013', '%m/%d/%Y'))
GROUP BY attendance.username , DAY(attendance.date)
```